# Codeception: '$I->see($text,$Selector)' throws error : 'stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document'

Tags: php, ui-automation, codeception

The following code in codeception threw error:

```
$I->see($text,$Selector);
```

Error received:

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

There are couple of solutions available online for stale element error, however none of them are codeception specific.
I am new to codeception and finding it difficult to resolve this error using codeception specific methods & syntax.

Appreciate your help in resolving the error so that I will be able to read the text inside the webelement without getting the stale element reference error.

Answer (score 0):

The 'see' method first takes an element then check for the text.
Probably javascript change the element the same time when codeception check it and Stale error occurs.

You can just add some wait time before see or catch the exception and try again.

```
$I->wait(2); //  wait 2 seconds before call the see method
$I->see($text, $selector);
```

Sometimes servers are busy so may be try/catch is better solution.

```
try {
    $I->see($text, $selector);
} catch (StaleElementReferenceException $e) {
    $I->wait(2);
    $I->see($text, $selector);
}
```